# composer update error. Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, composer-php, command

When I try to update composer, it will show some error. does anyone know how to solve it? i'm using Mac

> $ composer update
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - acquia/blt[9.0.4, ..., 9.0.5] require composer-plugin-api ^1.0.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
> - acquia/blt[9.1.0, ..., 9.2.8] require composer-plugin-api ^1.1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
> - Root composer.json requires acquia/blt ^9.0.4 -> satisfiable by acquia/blt[9.0.4, ..., 9.2.8].

Comment: Package acquia/blt in this version not compatible with composer v2. Downgrade composer to v1, update package to current version - then update composer again

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? `acquia/blt`  in v9 is pretty old (last release in May 2019), so why not update it?